# Within Subjects Design question

Tags: mixed-model, experiment-design

I have 75 participants and each participant has an exam on 15 questions. These questions are words. Their answers are 0 and 1 (known-unknown). Then I have another variable, their fixation on those words in a text: it is continuous (300 milliseconds for example). The data in long form looks like this.

[image]

And it goes on. For each participant I have 15 variables as 0 and 1 (index variables). I hypothesize that participants look longer at unknown words. But I cannot figure out the accurate procedure. I need millisecond means for 0 and 1 and the significance but it inflates my degrees of freedom (more than 1100) although I have only 75 participants.

I use spss, all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did each participant see exactly the same list of words or were there randomly choose? This sounds like a logistic regression or mixed-effects model problem. Also notice that the `descriptive-statistics` tag seems to be unrelated and can be misleading.

Comment: I edited your tags, please check if they are correct and if not edit them to be more precise.

Comment: Yes Tim, all learners saw the same words, same text, everthing is same. But their answers differ, some knew many words, some did not. Thanks for editing also.

Answer (score 0):

I would model the fixation time with a mixed effects model, with a random intercept for `ID`, and maybe also a random slope within `ID`. Using the R package `lme4` such a model could be written as

```
lme4::lmer( fixation ~ index*answer + (1 | ID), data=your_data_frame )
```

which means that `index`, `answer` and their interaction are fixed effects while there is a random intercept within `ID`. But the difference in time between known and unknown words could well differ between persons, so a random slope seems needed, leading to

```
lme4::lmer( fixation ~ index*answer + (1 + answer | ID), data=your_data_frame )
```